# Are Windows Services not appropriate as Microservices?

Tags: windows, service, microservices

Are Windows Services not appropriate as Microservices?
Hear allot about ASP.Net Web Api Microservices but i need to write a service that listens to a queue, are Windows Services ok for this?

Comment: flagged to close as too broad question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microservices are a logical concept. what technology you use is irrelevant as long as you adhere to the principles of the architecture. so yes, you can use Windows Services as long as they are *microservices*.

Comment: I see at most Microsoft events these days Windows Services are regarded as legacy, it all seems to be Azure and Auzre functions and logic apps these days :-S